# Resources.Designers.cs を自動で更新したい

Tags: visual-studio

外部の自作ツールで Resources.resx を上書き更新しているのですが、そのままでは Resources.Designers.cs が更新されません。

VisualStudio で Resources.resx を開いて保存操作をすることで Resources.Designers.cs は更新されるのですが、毎回手間ですのでこれを自動化したいと考えています。

どのようにすれば実現できるでしょうか？

---

- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- .NET Framework 4.7.2, WPF

Comment: どのタイミングで更新されることを望みますか？ ビルド時とか？

Comment: この辺の記事が同様の話題を扱っているようです。何かヒントになれば。[Create designer.cs file from ResXRersourcewriter generated resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14153933/9014308)、[Automatically move all the control properties from a resx file to a designer.cs code file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48755247/9014308)、[Do I need the resx Designer.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217173/9014308)、[“Run Custom Tool” for resx files in MVC2 project (from an external application/script)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3230585/9014308)

Comment: Resources.resx 更新時に同時に更新されるのが理想です。外部自作ツールから何らかの信号を送って Resources.Designers.cs を更新させたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resources.Designers.cs`は.NET Framework 2.0で追加された**厳密に型指定されたリソースクラス**を格納するソースコードファイルです。このコードを生成する方法はいくつかあります。

- [StronglyTypedResourceBuilder Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)
  以下の方法はいずれも最終的にはこのクラスを用いてコード生成しています。.NETクラスライブラリの一部ですので「外部の自作ツール」に埋め込むことも可能です。
- [ResGen.exe; リソース ファイル ジェネレーター](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator)
  `/str`オプションでコード生成することができます。
- [GenerateResource タスク](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/msbuild/generateresource-task?view=vs-2019)
  ビルド時に`.resx`ファイルから`.resources`ファイルを生成するタスクですが、パラメーターを指定することで、コード生成させることもできます。
- Run Custom Tool
  Solution Explorerの`.resx`を右クリックし`Run Custom Tool`をクリックするとカスタムツールが実行されます。`.resx`の場合はコード生成されるよう構成されています。